# Prove $D(a;R_1,R_2)$ is a connected set

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis, metric-spaces, connectedness, path-connected

I was solving problems from the start of my Complex Analysis course, and I found this one (the beggining of my course focuses a lot in topology):

> Prove that $D(a; R_1,R_2)$ is a connected set.

The notation $D(a;R_1,R_2)$ refers to the *open disk* of center $a$ and with radius greater that $R_1$ but lower that $R_2$ (I guess, because this is the first time I see a disk notation with two different radius, tell me if I'm wrong) (Personally, I prefer the *ball* notation, but this is the one my course notes use). Also consider I'm working inside the metric space $(\mathbb{C},d)$, where $d$ is the euclidean metric function. To be said:

$$D(a;R_1,R_2)=\{z\in\mathbb{C} : |z-a|>R_1, |z-a|<R_2\}$$

Intuitively, I understand this set is connected, since it's like a "donut", but I have trouble proving it by using the definition of connected space, to be said, proving *it isn't union of to open (or closed) sets*. I'm not sure if the concept of *connected by arcs* is useful here, though I clearly see it in my mind I don't know how to write a consistent proof of it.

How can I proof that set is connected? Any help will be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: Is your problem that you don't know how to prove it is arc-connected or that you don't know that arc-connectedness implies connectedness?

Comment: @RobArthan My problem is proving it, I already know path-connectedness implies connectedness (I don't even know if proving path-connectedness is easier than directly proving connectedness in this example).

Comment: If a space is path-connected, then that is usually the easy way to show it is connected. To see that this space is path-connected, design a path from $z$ to $w$ that first follows an arc of a circle to get to the ray from $a$ to $w$ and then goes along the ray to get to $w$.

Comment: @RobArthan Thanks for your help! I'll try it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These things are often called "annuli" (in the singular, "annulus"), from the Latin for something that looks like a ring.  It makes intuitive sense that these things are arcwise connected because there is nothing stopping you from drawing a curve from any point in one of these things to any other without leaving the annulus.

If you want example formulas, I'll handle the case $a = 0$ because it's simple.  In polar form, $D(a,R_1,R_2) = \{r e^{i\theta}: R_1 < r < R_2\}$.  I'll just write $D$ for this set.

Fix any $z$ and $w$ in $D$ and choose positive $r_0, r_1$, and real $\theta_0$ and $\theta_1$ such that $z = r_0 e^{\theta_0}$ and $w = r_1 e^{\theta_1}$.  Note that because $z$ and $w$ are in $D$, $r_0$ and $r_1$ are both in the real interval $(R_1, R_2)$.

Consider the path $\gamma: [0,1] \to \mathbb{C}$ given by
$$
\gamma(t) = ((1-t) r_0 + t r_1) \exp(i((1-t) t_0 + t \theta_1)), \qquad t \in [0,1].
$$
Convince yourself that $\gamma$ is continuous and that $\gamma(0) = z$ and $\gamma(1) = w$, and it may help to think geometrically about what $\gamma$ does.  As $t$ goes from $0$ to $1$ it just moves the modulus and angle from that of $z$ to that of $w$ in a linear way; it'll look a bit like part of a spiral or something - maybe graph a few examples.

Fix $t$.  We have that
$$
|\gamma(t)| = (1-t) r_0 + t r_1
$$
Convince yourself via the fact that $r_0, r_1$ are both in $(R_1, R_2)$ that $|\gamma(t)| \in (R_1, R_2)$ also.  (In other language $|\gamma(t)|$ is a "convex combination" of $r_0$ and $r_1$ and $r_2$, so will lie in any convex set that contains $r_1$ and $r_2$.  But you don't need this language to verify the simple inequalities.)  So $|\gamma(t)| \in D$.

So $\gamma$ is an arc in $D$ connecting $z$ to $w$.  Since $z$ and $w$ were arbitrary, $D$ is arcwise connected.

The general case could be handled via a use of this case, or by just adding "$a+$" to a lot of the formulas.